# Kill the interpreter with argparse

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, argparse

I'm testing out some argparse code. I wanted to have an optional argument, which collects `n` number of inputs from a list of choices. So, I wrote:

```
import argparse

modules = ["geo", "loc"]
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("--modules", nargs='*', choices=modules)
```

With this set up, I'm reliably able to kill the interpreter completely.

It works fine if you pass a valid set of arguments:

```
>>> parser.parse_args("--module geo loc geo".split())
Namespace(modules=['geo', 'loc', 'geo'])
```

But if you pass in a miss formed argument, it kills python completely:

```
>>> parser.parse_args("--module geo metro".split())
usage: [-h] [--modules [{geo,loc} [{geo,loc} ...]]]
: error: argument --modules: invalid choice: 'metro' (choose from 'geo', 'loc')
PS C:\Users\myname\mycode>
```

My question is two-fold:

1. Is this expected behavior? If so, what is the reasoning for this?
2. Will I be okay using this code, since I don't mind if my program dies with ill-formed arguments? Or is there some compelling reason to avoid this?

As a note, I am using Python2.7 on Windows 7.

Comment: `parser_args` calls some `error` function that calls `sys.exit`. That is why you get that behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Yes, this is intended, and documented:

   > While parsing the command line, parse_args() checks for a variety of errors, including ambiguous options, invalid types, invalid options, wrong number of positional arguments, etc. When it encounters such an error, it exits and prints the error along with a usage message:

   The idea is that, if the user gives an invalid option or argument which you don't know how to handle, the best option is to give up instead of second-guess the user's actual intentions.
2. If you don't mind, then it should be ok, right? Unless you know a reason to implement different behavior, your program is completely consistent with all well-behaved command line tools on all platforms.

If you do want to implement different behavior, catch the `SystemExit` exception that `parse_args` might raise.

(The only program that I can think of that behaves differently from the way I just described is the version control tool Git, which does try to guess what the user meant and prints its guesses. It then still exits, though.)

Answer (score 1):

`argparse` is designed for use when your Python script is run from a command line. That's why invalid arguments cause the program to quit.

This behavior is consistent with virtually all shell (bash/sh/dos/etc.) utilities. Invalid command line args cause the program to quit with an error string and (optionally) a usage message.